# How to add more options on setting?

Tags: settings

How can I add more features on Android's settings. I saw some difference on my CM ROM's settings , how does the developer add new features or option on setting? Is it related with framework?

I want to add Newton interface like this screen shot.

[image]

Comment: You can't unless you flash a ROM that had these features. [Edit] to add device details and Android version

Comment: You need to build your own custom ROM for it.

Answer (score 1):

You *can't* add features and generally *customize Settings*.
 Some features are added by android rom (During upgrades, ...) and  **Developer Options** can be added using this trick:
goto: `Settings` -> `About Phone` -> Press `Build Number` multiple times.